# I sent vs I sent out

Tags: verbs

Which one is correct and why:

> I **sent out** the inquiry to the support team

vs

> I **sent** the inquiry to the support team

Even though the question is specific to "*sent out*", please verify the correct usage usage of articles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"send out" is generally used when you send something in bulk to a group (often large) of people, as opposed to simply "send" which is generally used when issuing something to someone in particular, or to a certain place.

In this case, "support team" tends to refer to the support *department* instead of *its members*, so I would say the second sentence makes more sense.

Answer (score 5):

In  your first example

> I sent out the inquiry to the support team.

The *out* is superfluous. You could tighten it up by just saying

> I sent the inquiry to the support team.

If you don't have a specific party to whom you sent the inquiry, use *out*.

> I sent out the inquiry.

This has the connotation that you sent the inquiry out to multiple people.

Comment: what about *reaching out* ?

Comment: @vehomzzz: What about it?

Comment: Does the same rule apply as to sent? reaching out to one person seems correct

Comment: @vehomzz: The *reach out/reach* case is not comparable to that of *send out/send*. One can either *reach out to* someone or *reach* someone. Different shades of meaning and this has nothing to do with whether it is to one person or to multiple people.

Comment: @vehomzz: You might want to ask another question to get a proper answer to this ;)

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of *verb*+*out* constructions that can be generalized to the following:

- *sent* = "sent to one or more people"
- *sent out* = "sent to multiple people"

Other examples: *pass/pass out*, *hand/hand out*, *give/give out*, *speak/speak out*.

The *out*-form has this sense of going out to more than one person.  This does not work for all *verb+out* forms, but there is a certain domain where this *out* extension is productive in English in this sense.

Comment: what about *reaching out* ?

Comment: @vehomzzz: Personally, I would consider that *out* to be more of the directional type, like "stretch out" or "lunge out", but in some cases it can be difficult to decide.