# "Sent" vs "sent off" vs "sent out"

Tags: verbs, adverbs, phrasal-verbs

When do we use one over another?

> I **sent** a letter.
>
> I **sent off** a letter.
>
> I **sent out** a letter.

[Here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8730/i-sent-vs-i-sent-out) I found a similar topic but I am still confused.

> **sent** = sent to one or more people
>
> **sent out** = sent to multiple people

*More people* and *multiple people* mean the same to me. So how do we distinguish which one is the right one to use?

Comment: Each is roughly interchangeable. There is little or no meaningful difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three **to send**, **to send off**, and **to send out** are distinguished by their motion and direction (actually and metaphorically).

**To send** is simply the action of causing something to go somewhere.

**To Send off** is the action of causing something to go somewhere from where you are to somewhere else.

**To Send out** is the action of causing something to go away from you.

From those literal uses we derive our metaphorical or analogical use.

For example, "I sent out a newsletter", because I am issuing the letter away myself to others. Or "we sent off the letter yesterday", because of the motion from ourselves to the recipient.

Others which describe a similar motion are:

**To send away**: the action of sending something to somewhere you are not.

**To send along**: the action of sending something in a particular direction, or along a particular path.

**To send forth**: the action of sending something toward somewhere

(edited to fix markdown)

Comment: All of those are nicely separable. Send something off, send something out, send something away, send something along, send something forth.

Comment: It’s an opinion and not criticism. Isn't "causing something to go somewhere from where you are to somewhere else." equal to "causing something to go away from you"? To me, the definitions don't really clarify the difference, not because the answer is incorrect, but because there’s not much difference between these phrasal verbs. Base on my poor understanding of English and my daily observations living in an English-speaker country, people create phrasal verbs as they talk. Assuming that some of those verbs contribute to clarify concepts, I wonder whether all of those in use are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

We **send** an email. (talks about the process of sending).

We have revised the email several times, now it's time to **send it off**.  (finally!)

We **send out** newsletters (to a group of people).

Comment: Welcome to [english.se]! Are you saying "We send newsletters (to a group of people)." or "We send out an email (to our boss)." cannot be used?